# HTTP Protocol: How does one figure out where a site's homepage is located

Tags: ruby, http, sockets, networking, protocols

I can't be the only person to have ever wondered this, but I couldn't find the question answered anywhere else on the site. I've successfully requested specific files from sites by sending HTTP requests (in ruby with sockets). I don't know, however, how to find out what file a site's homepage is located in to start with. I think this question is fairly clear, but just in case:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.new("www.example.edu", 80)
s.print("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")

while (t = s.recv(50))
        print t
end

exit 0
```

That's what does work, but what I would like to do is get a homepage without knowing its file name beforehand. Anyone know? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the other way around: you request just `/` (i.e. `GET / HTTP/1.1`) and then the *webserver* decides to lookup `index.html`. Or any other document/script/whatever that has been configured.

This often happens to be `index.html`, but is not necessarily so. Often it will be `index.php` or similar.

My default apache configuration says:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
```

I could put anything in there.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That's so much simpler than I thought it would be.